# QGIS 3.45 Layers Panel point data labels set too far apart

Tags: qgis, layers, sql-server-spatial, panel

[image][image]The Layers Panel in v 2.18 is fine but we are now trying to go live with 3.45 and are experiencing issues with the display of some layers in the panel.

Layers that are generated from an MSSQL spatial Database are displaying so that the symbology is so stretched out that it is unreadable.

If I go to the Layer Properties and click apply it reverts to what it should look like but as soon as I leave properties and interact with the layer i.e. try and untick a symbol it immediately extends the symbols so far below the layer heading that I can't see them. It also removes the label but retains the symbol.

Comment: pics or it didn't happen (ie please add a screenshot so we can see the issue you're describing)

Comment: Before and after images added